# Set up webpack to pull JS file from local rather than via HTTP

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-module-federation

webpack.config.js pulls remote js for Module Federation.

```
plugins: [
  new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    remotes: {
      'mfe1': "mfe1@http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/remoteEntry.js"
    }
  })
],
```

How can I use a local JS file in remotes or in addition to remotes? I have a simple react.js library in the other folder, with `./dist/browser/remote-entry.js` file in it. I cannot publish to npm, so I'm trying to load it from local. Would it be something like:

```
plugins: [
  new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    remotes: {
      'mfe1': "../../myproject/dist/browser/remoteEntry.js"
    }
  })
],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `remotes` entry is supposed to be a `url` that is accessible during run-time, not build-time. If it was only necessary during build-time, it would automatically imply that the `remoteEntry` gets bundled, which defeats the purpose of Webpack Module Federation (`WMF` for short).

You say:

> webpack.config.js pulls remote js for Module Federation.

But I'm not sure what that is supposed to mean. Webpack does not "pull" the remote files at all. It tells the final build where to look, so that when your code (i.e. `bundle.js`) actually executes, it knows from where to load modules dynamically.
This means that, in order for `WMF` to work, you still need to serve the file from your web server.

You primarily have two choices:

1. If you don't want dynamic loading of modules, just build your project without `WMF`.
2. If you do want dynamic loading, then you need to tell webpack that `remotes` url. Ideally, you can get the actual server address from `process.env`, which you can provide via [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) (or through many other means):

**webpack.config.js**

```js
// ...
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      remotes: {
        'mfe1': `mfe1@${process.env.REMOTE_HOST || 'http://localhost:8080'}/remoteEntry.js`
      }
    })
  ],
  // ...
};
```

**.env**

```
REMOTE_HOST=http://xxxxxxxxxx.com
```

Also, you might want to consider [this article on how to deploy a `WMF` build](https://medium.com/swlh/deploying-micro-frontends-to-aws-step-by-step-using-react-webpack-5-and-module-federation-3f97f6f1658c).

Comment: I thought I can just point to a local remoteEntry.js file somehow since I cannot publish it... Do you propose to run local webserver and access remoteEntry.js via HTTP?

Comment: @JohnGlabb Usually you run `WMF` with `webpack-dev-server` (at least in `development` mode) anyway. If you follow any of the samples, it is already working automatically. You don't really have to do anything, other than making sure that your config is correct, and you are dynamically importing the `expose`d components.

Comment: I didn't understand from this answer whether it is impossible to use relative URL for the remote like it is possible to use in a standard fetch request

Comment: @DrorBar That is up to the `WMF` implementation to decide. It keeps evolving. Not sure if their specs state anything on that (if they even have specs at this point). It might work with a current version, it might work in a future version, it might never work :shrug: